# C# If statement where date is this month

Tags: c#, date, if-statement, filehelpers

```
string month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
string CommandText = "SELECT slocref.slocname, partstuff.quantity, partstuff.currency, partstuff.postingdate" + " FROM partstuff INNER JOIN slocref ON partstuff.sloc = slocref.slocvalue";
```

This is the code to get date and month.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(rdr["postingdate"].ToString(), "0" + month + "*"))
{
    if (rdr["slocname"].ToString() == "Answer/Slatwall")
    {
        string quantity = rdr["quantity"].ToString();
        string currency = rdr["currency"].ToString();
        answertotalmonth += float.Parse(currency);
        label100.Text = "$" + answertotalmonth.ToString("#,##0.00");
    }
}
```

This is just an example of the code that is run by the if statement.

But the if statement needs to get all of the July information and add it up. So from 07/01/2012 to 07/31/2012. I cannot change the SQL because it messes up the rest of the program. I tried to get the current date, add the 0 in front of it, then use a wildcard.

Need a little direction on this if statement.

Let me clarify this post. The "postingdate" value comes from FileHelpers. Importing a text file by fixed width into these values. The postingdate value looks like "07/16/12"

So, I want to get this current month, and then if a postingdate value has that month's value, run the if statement code.

Comment: are those somenick234 real accounts or generated from some software/other website?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot change the SQL, because it messes up the rest of the program"?  Do you mean the command is used elsewhere, or that you can't come up with the correct SQL syntax?  If you can get the proper data back from the database, it will likely make your life a lot easier (and your program a lot more efficient).

Comment: Like I said, I'm a beginner. I tried two SQL statements and two readers at one point, and could not get it to work. That is what I meant by "it messes up the program"

Comment: @Peri To which other accounts are you referring?

Comment: @Ricardo. I see a lot of nicknames like xxx123, yyy234. They almost always have no reputation. Suspected they are not real SO accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do this?

```
 if (Regex.IsMatch(rdr["postingdate"].ToString(), "0" + month + "*"))
```

If rdr["postingdate"] is supposed to be a date, convert it to a date time and do a sensible comparison.

```
if(DateTime.TryParse(rdr["postingdate"].ToString(), rdrDateTime))
{
    // proceed as planned
    if (rdrDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month) 
    {
       // and so on.
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. I do not know too much, but should have been able to think of parsing it as a date. I am trying it now.

Comment: Your example helped me to get it working. Thanks for the quick answer. I feel a little stupid, but I'm learning. Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that you'll probably want to handle the DateTime.TryParse statement if it fails -- what should your program do if the rdr["postingdate"] is _not_ valid?

Comment: The way the date is put into the access database through my other program that uses FileHelper, the text file has many spaces around the value. Access then stores it without the spaces. FileHelpers would throw an error if it did not get put in correctly. I have wrote for it to just skip that value in my other program. The values are mostly a few cents and this program is just a representation. A few cents does not hurt. So far, FileHelpers has not had an error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you problem correctly but why don't you just match the DataTime's month property:

```
if( date.Month == month)
{
   //your code...
}
```

Also like mentioned above, you can parse the text as a date. But if you are just interested in just the month that may not be necessary.

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, you would have to check the year as well. So it would be better to pares as a full DateTime object.

Comment: Indeed, it would appear that most of the problems stem from the fact that he's using _everything_ as a string, instead of using the types relevant to the data.

Comment: You need to check the year and the month; otherwise, you'll get all data from the given month *in all years.*

Comment: @phoog but that may be ok for the task at hand. Who can say?

Comment: @ReacherGilt of course, but in the absence of a specific requirement that guarantees it wouldn't be a problem, it's safer to assume that it would be.  (Plus, this is a bug that I've run into more than once in real code.)